# Linq: Get Item which is in a list which also is in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently trying to get a list of products which are in a list of stores but only if the product name is the same.

I always get 0 Items back.

I tried to solve to problem using two different approaches, which are below.

```
//First Approach, return 0
var stores= Store.ReadAll().Where(prods => 
prods.Products.Contains(product))

//Second Approach, doesn't compile but it shows what i wan't to do.

var stores= Store.ReadAll().Where(prods => 
prods.Products.Where(p => p.ProductName == productName));
```

Help appreciated :)

Comment: Please show the definition and initialization of `productName`; the name suggests a string, is that the actual type? Please also show the definition of the member type of the list.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you have a list of products and you want to get all products from all stores which are in your product list?

Comment: Use `Select()` to get a specific attribute or property and `ToList()` to get the list from query.

Comment: The type is a string, correct. I'm trying to get a list of stores which contains a product, sounds simple but it just doesn't want to work. I also updated the code, because i noticed that the variable name is missleading. Greetings

Comment: As we have little info from your question I might also suggest that you may need to consider case sensitivity too when comparing the product name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Any` instead of `Where`:

```
var products = Store.ReadAll().Where(prods => prods.Products.Any(p => p.ProductName == productName));
```

Answer (score 0):

So i partly solved my problem and apparently, it wasn't really a linq problem, it was a database problem. I have a List of objects which contains a list of objects, which gives me a M:M relation. But the .net Entity Framework didn't regonize when i changed the list using list.add(item). So my list was always empty.

But anyway, thanks for the help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `stores` is an IEnumerable type, then following should work. It's important to pass the second parameter to Contains method, so comparision is not case sensitive, else it will return nothing if case is different between product names.

I have assumed in my answer that Store type has a property called Products of List< string > type.

```
var matchingStores = stores.Where(s=> s.Products.Contains(productName,
                                                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```